# How to read a complex JSON in spring batch?

Tags: json, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a complex JSON below. I am reading it using FlatFileItemReader. How can I ignore the last line "]", with my customized ComplexJsonRecordSeparatorPolicy?

```
[
  {"firstName":"Tom", "lastName":"Cruise"}, 
  {"firstName":"Bruce", "lastName":"Willis"},
  {"firstName":"Liam", "lastName":"Neeson"}
]
```

My ComplexJsonRecordSeparatorPolicy looks like below. This class is successfully working, when I have "]" in line no 4 but, it throws an error when the line is supplied with only "]" in line no 5, as my post processor deletes the line instead of ignoring it.

```
public class ComplexJsonRecordSeparatorPolicy extends JsonRecordSeparatorPolicy {

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfRecord(String line) {

        return StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(line, "{") == StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(line, "}")
                && (line.trim().endsWith("}") || line.trim().endsWith(",") || line.trim().endsWith("]"));
    }

    @Override
    public String postProcess(String record) {
        if (record.startsWith("["))
            record = record.substring(1);
        if ((record.endsWith("]") || record.endsWith(",")))
            record = record.substring(0, record.length() - 1);
        return super.postProcess(record);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576974/json-array-reader-file-with-spring-batch

Comment: You already posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468595/spring-batch-how-to-read-and-write-a-json

Comment: @NghiaDo The link does not solve the problem I have stated.

Comment: @TheGuest I have posted a diferent question there.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a small example for this one. Please take a look and let me know your thoughts

https://github.com/bigzidane/spring-batch-jsonListItem-reader.

For more information, I have created a Reader which is to parse JSON as a List and then map every entry to a POJO through 'classToBound' and then return each by each follow Spring Batch standard.

**The example takes an Json file as**

```
[
    {
        "name": "zidane",
        "nation": "france"
    },
    {
        "name": "ronaldo",
        "nation": "brazil"
    },
    {
        "name": "marcelo",
        "nation": "brazil"
    }
]
```

**The job configuration**

```
<job id="exampleJsonReaderJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="stepId">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="exampleJsonReader" writer="exampleWriter" processor="exampleProcessor" commit-interval="5" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>
```

**The Reader**

```
<bean id="exampleJsonReader" class="com.itservicesdepot.example.springbatch.jsonreader.reader.JsonFileListItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:soccers.json" />
        <property name="classToBound" value="com.itservicesdepot.example.springbatch.jsonreader.model.SoccerJsonEntry" />
    </bean>
```

The Processor and Writer are just normal ones.

In the reader, there is an property "classToBound", that is the Pojo which is top map with an item in Json list.