# Process json files in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a zip file containing multiple json files. I have unzipped them
then got POJO object from json using below code:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Element[] people = gson.fromJson(reader, Element[].class);
```

but I need to process these json files one by one using spring batch.
Can someone help me how I can achieve this in spring batch and I want to read json file using chunk of 1000
My json object is very complex. Example:

```
{
    "students": {
      "subelements": {
          "dep": {
            "data": [
              "XYZ"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: What represents an item in this file? Which fragment corresponds to the `Element` class?

Comment: Element is main class which holds id, type and list of properties

Comment: elements is list of items (    "elements": { })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure is not one of the types you could handle with Spring Batch out-of-the-box. See more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51933062/5019386.

So I think in your case, you would need to create a custom item reader to parse a specific fragment of your input file.

Comment: Can I read just list of items(elements array) using spring batch? and ignore all other json data during reading

Comment: No that's not possible. Your file needs to be of the form `[{object1}, {object2}, {object3}]` to be able to use the `JsonItemReader`.

Comment: so then best is to use json stream api ?

Comment: Exactly, your custom item reader should use a json streaming api.